# Storing the physical address of the image then changing it?

Tags: asp.net, image, directory

I have a folder which is in my machine right now and has some images .the location of these images is stored in the database.i want to know what i should do move these images to another location..the path saved in the DB will not change ..?how do deal with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can tell the http handler which takes care of the pics-   to go to the other location.

a code from my old project :

```
namespace ImageHandler
{
    public class HttpImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/usa.png"); // here you should play with the location
            context.Response.WriteFile(path);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

### in web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.gif"     type="ImageHandler.HttpImageHandler"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the path in the DB, you may have to create a filesystem link (a kind of shortcut) so it appears to anything using the files that they are in the original location. Have a look at [NTFS junction points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) (assuming you're running on Windows), or on Linux, the `ln` tool.

Out of interest, why can't you change the path in the DB?

Comment: well right now the application is hosted on my local machine and all the image address are stored in the DB pointing to my local drive..when i move it to a server or another address the DB will still be having the same address as my local machine..i need to deal with that issue..what if i have like 10,000 images..changing the address in the DB would be a task if i am not wrong.

Comment: Then just write a script to change each record individually in the DB. It's not going to be exceedingly fast, but it doesn't need to be as you're doing it once. Also, don't store the absolute path to each image, just store it relative to the site root or a folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to move the files, perhaps you could do a Bulk DB update for the existing paths, like replacing a certain pattern (from \OldFolder... to \NewFolder...).